# Atualizando multiplas linhas e campos do Mysql

Tags: mysql, query

Montei um Query MySQL com o objetivo de atualizar um campo em várias linhas de minha tabela Mysql. Ficou da seguinte forma:

```
update produtos set (nome) = case codigo
when 5 then 'teste 1'
when 6 then 'teste 2'
when 7 then 'teste 3'
where codigo in (5,6,7)
```

Funcionou perfeitamente.

Gostaria, no entanto, de atualizar em paralelo outros campos, como quantidade.
Como adequo a seguinte query acima para tornar isso possível?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É só você colocar uma virgula a cada campo:

```
UPDATE produtos SET
    nome = CASE codigo
        WHEN 5 THEN 'teste 1'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'teste 2'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'teste 3'
    END, campo2 = "valor2", campo3 = "valor3"
WHERE codigo IN (5,6,7);
```

Esse `END` antes da virgula, significa o fim do `CASE`, evite esquece-lo pra não receber o seguinte erro:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near

Answer (score 1):

Outra solução que encontrei no link abaixo utilizando "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE":

https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/11/how-to-update-multiple-rows-at-once-in-mysql.html

Segue abaixo o código de exemplo adaptado para a sua solução:

```
INSERT INTO repostas 
    (id, resposta)
    VALUES 
        (1, "$_POST['1']"),
        (2, "$_POST['2']"),
        (3, "$_POST['3']"),
        (4, "$_POST['4']")
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        resposta = VALUES(resposta);
```